# "Currency converter" one of the main keywords in website

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using big commerce platform, and while checking my website through woorank, I noticed something weird, not sure if its website error or big commerce is crazy. but the phrase "Currency converter" was one of the highest rankings on my website, which is not very efficient is it... Anyone know if its a bug or if it's real, maybe you know how I could fix it? Attaching image. [H2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpJKY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This image is indicating that Currency Converted is using a Header 2 tag, not that it is high ranking. This is a stylistic change on the storefront.

Answer (score 0):

please go to `edit html/css` - and search `topmenu`

Please remove the following lines:

```
<div class="top-currency mobile">%%Panel.SideCurrencySelector%%</div>
<li class="top-currency">%%Panel.SideCurrencySelector%%</li>
```